# PhpStorm does not recognize HTML tags correctly

Tags: html, angular, angular6, phpstorm

I'm trying to write an HTML file in PhpStorm and I got a bunch of errors. I'm not sure how to explain it, so I will link a screenshot below.

Basically I got an error at each HTML tag and error message like

> TS2365 Operator '>' cannot be applied to string and number

I have not enabled TSLint and my file mapping is correct.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what's the file extension and set language of that file extension?

Comment: @treyBake it's an .html file and the mapping is correctly set under HTML.

Comment: Hmm, copying your code line for line in my PHPStorm doesn't flag it with errors. .... when you start a new .html file what option is the type dropdown set to?

Comment: @treyBake you mean the kind dropdown ? it set to HTML 5 file, HTML 4 file and XHTML file

Comment: o.O how can it be all 3 at once?

Comment: No, i can choose what kind of HTML file i want. By default it set to HTML 5

Comment: Ah ok haha mine is likewise set to that and seems to all work - do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: I have the Angular plugins installed. I guess i could remove each one and find out if anyone causes trouble. Let me try that.

Comment: ^^ best way to start :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WEB-36373](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36373) is fixed in 2018.3.3.

For now, I can suggest turning *Angular language service* off in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript** (all the angular functionality will still be available)